# Pinging multiple times using InetAddress makes GUI unresponsive

Tags: java, netbeans, ping, inetaddress

My program is to ping a host infinitely and display each ping result on the GUI as RED/GREEN. Here, 'res' is a label that changes its text and background based on the ping result.

The issue is that when i use while(), the GUI becomes unresponsive and the colour of the label does not change, while the ping service continues. How do i solve this issue??

```
while (true) {
        try {
            boolean status = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut);

            if (status == true) {
                res.setText("ON");
                res.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                res.setText("OFF");
                res.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Essentially, from your description, you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from process new events, including paint events.

Swing is also NOT thread safe, this means you should not update the UI from outside of the context of the EDT.

In this case, you could use a `SwingWorker` to perform the physical "ping" from within the `doInBackground` method and make use of the `publish`/`process` methods to update the UI.

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: how do i retrieve the info from the thread that the ping was successful or not?

Comment: `SwingWorker` has a `done` method, you can then call `SwingWorker#get` which return what ever you want or will throw an exception if something went wrong in the `doInBackground` method.  You can also use a `PropertyChangeListener` an monitor for the `state` change event, when the `SwingWorker`'s state changes to `DONE`, you call it's `get` method